# Backbone Marionette and RequireJS Modules Confusion – module seems to be undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs, marionette

I just got started using Marionette and I'm reading and following along [Marionette - A Gentle Introduction](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction) by [David Sulc](https://github.com/davidsulc). It's a really good read and it's easy to follow along building the sample application *Contact Manager* with the [companion repository](https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction).

However, I had previously set up a project using RequireJS and wanted to translate and integrate the ideas and concepts of that book into this project. I haven't actually gotten that far and I think I might be a little bit confused about the use of Marionette Modules in combination with AMD modules which leads to `undefined` objects.

To be more specific, let me list `app.js`, `listView.js` and `listController.js` which should be the RequireJS version of this [commit of the sample repo](https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/commit/ada556f84092d45d3731f86c495a60e2d95af3c7).

**app.js**

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'marionette'
], function ( Marionette ) {
    'use strict';

    var ContactManager = new Marionette.Application();

    ContactManager.addRegions({
        mainRegion : '#main-region'
    });

    ContactManager.on( 'initialize:after', function() {

        ContactManager.ContactsApp.List.Controller.listContacts();
    });

    return ContactManager;
});
```

**listView.js**

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'app',
    'marionette',
    'handlebars',
    'text!templates/contact.hbs'
], function ( ContactManager, Marionette, Handlebars, contactTemplate ) {
    'use strict';

    var List = ContactManager.module( 'ContactsApp.List' );

    List.Contact = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        tagName: 'li',
        template : Handlebars.compile( contactTemplate ),

    });

    List.Contacts = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

        tagName: 'ul',
        itemView: List.Contact
    });

    return List;
});
```

**listController.js**

```
/*global define*/
define([
    'app'
], function ( ContactManager ) {
    'use strict';

    var List = ContactManager.module( 'ContactsApp.List');

    List.Controller = {

        listContacts: function() {

            var contacts = ContactManager.request('contact:entities');

            var contactsListView = new ContactManager.ContactsApp.List.Contacts({
                collection: contacts
            });

            ContactManager.mainRegion.show( contactsListView );
        }
    };

    return List.Controller;
});
```

So, the error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'List' of undefined` in `app.js:15` which refers to this line:

`ContactManager.ContactsApp.List.Controller.listContacts();`

This means that the `ContactsApp` module is `undefined` and this is exactly what I don't understand.

To my understanding I attach the `ContactsApp` module and the `List` sub-module to the `ContactManager` inside either `listView.js` or `listController.js` (whichever is called first) with the line:

`ContactManager.module( 'ContactsApp.List' );`

Shouldn't the `ContactsApp` be defined inside `app.js` then?

This is the **main.js** file which includes the `require.config` and the entry point to the application:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: './scripts',
    paths: {
        jquery     : '../bower_components/jquery/jquery',
        underscore : '../bower_components/underscore/underscore',
        backbone   : '../bower_components/backbone/backbone',
        marionette : '../bower_components/backbone.marionette/lib/backbone.marionette',
        bootstrap  : '../bower_components/sass-bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap',
        text       : '../bower_components/requirejs-text/text',
        handlebars : '../bower_components/handlebars/handlebars',
        templates  : '../templates'
    },

    shim: {
        underscore : {
            exports : '_'
        },
        backbone : {
            deps : [ 'underscore', 'jquery' ],
            exports : 'Backbone'
        },
        marionette : {
            deps : [ 'backbone' ],
            exports : 'Backbone.Marionette'
        },
        bootstrap : {
            deps : [ 'jquery' ],
        },
        handlebars : {
            exports : 'Handlebars'
        }
    },
    deps : [ 'jquery', 'underscore' ]
});

require([
    'app',
    'bootstrap'
], function ( ContactManager ) {
    'use strict';

    ContactManager.start();
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RequireJS bascially works like this: declare all the dependencies a given module has, then use them within the call back function.

Here's the issue with your code: in `app.js`, you require only `marionette` so as far as RequireJS is concerned, *nothing* else should be loaded for the module's code to be functional. But then, in that same file, you call `ContactManager.ContactsApp.List.Controller.listContacts()`. Where does that come from? Nowhere: it isn't defined within the current module, and wasn't declared as a dependency. Therefore, it doesn't exist and you get the `undefined` issue.

You can't just refer to the module, thinking it's attached to the main application: it only actually gets attached when the Marionette module code gets executed. And for that to happen, it needs to be required as a dependency.

As an aside, you'll have a tough time adapting the book's code to use with RequireJS, because it isn't architected for RequireJS use (in addition to the issue you ran into, you'll have circular dependencies, etc.).

I'd suggest you just read along the book to get a good feel for Marionette on its own, then look into using it with RequireJS. Shameless plug, I also wrote a [book on marionette and requirejs](https://leanpub.com/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, David. I thought it should be okay not to include the controller in `app.js` because I'm attaching the controller sub-module to the `ContactManager` inside `listController.js`. I assumed the controller would be available on the `ContactManager` in `app.js` then. Doesn't seem to be the case?!

If I include the the `listController` in the define block in `app.js`, I will run into a circular dependency again.

Would would be a good and clean way to do it then?

Comment: Also, I'm aware of your other book and I'm reading the source code as well but since I'm not very familiar with Marionette yet, not everything makes sense to me at this point. I guess I'll follow your advice and finish the book by itself and hope the structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette repo will make more sense to me then.

Comment: Does [Structuring Backbone Code with RequireJS and Marionette Modules](https://leanpub.com/structuring-backbone-with-requirejs-and-marionette) start with the finished Contact Manager app from [Backbone.Marionette.js: A Gentle Introduction](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction) and "translates" it to be used with RequireJS or do you start the app from scratch in this book?

Comment: I've edited my answer to clear up why the module being attached to the main app deosn't mean you can use it right away. The second book starts with the finished application and shows you how to "transform" it to use RequireJS. It also covers a few other topics on the way (e.g. mixing Marionette and RequireJS modules, starting/stoping modules according to routed paths)